# Dynamic number of except in try/except

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I would like to create a function that takes function as an argument and list of tuples. First element of a tuple will be an error and second one, a message. Example call:

```
handle_error(sum, [(ValueError, 'bad value'), (AttributeError, 'attribute error')])
```

This errors are meant to be handled in try/except blocks. I guess that it is not possible to dynamically define number of excepts. What is best practice to perform operation ilustrated as in the pseudocode example below?

```
def handle_error(function, errors):
    try:
        function()
    for error in errors:
        except error[0] as e:
           print(error[1])
```

I want to achieve such behaviour to make cleaner logging in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict` as `Exception`s are hashable.

```
from collections.abc import Callable  # just for type hinting.


def handle_error(callable_: Callable, error_dict: dict):
    try:
        callable_()
    except Exception as err:
        print(error_dict[type(err)])


# Testers
def tester(error_type):
    raise error_type()


# Test
handle_error(lambda: tester(ValueError), {ValueError: "bad val", AttributeError: "bad attr"})
handle_error(lambda: tester(AttributeError), {ValueError: "bad val", AttributeError: "bad attr"})
```

```
bad val
bad attr
```

As I see you call function without parameter I removed argument for callable from handler. You can still pass argument with use of `lambda` like above, but it's preferable to change handler's signature as following:

```
def handle_error(callable_: Callable, error_dict: dict, *args):
    try:
        callable_(*args)
```

Comment: The main problem is that function should be generic and number of excepts can vary depending on the function call. This do not solve the problem.

Comment: Example is meant to be applied to your idea, not a copy-paste solution of what you're doing. If you want fully implemented solution, I'll update accordingly.